# Skobbler MapRenderer Warning ProGuard

Tags: android, skmaps, android-proguard

I'm trying to create a release apk of my android project with Proguard. I obtain the following warning when I try to generate the signed apk:

[image]

I am using Skobbler SDK 2.5.1 and Android SDK compile version 23.

It seems that the problem is due to the class FloathMath that it is now deprecated.

Thanks in advance!

**(UPDATE1)**:

```
   Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/cancro/cancro:6.0.1/MMB29M/6.3.17:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 32188, tid: 32188, name: sal.bisite.example>>> es.usal.bisite.example<<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKCrossingDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/es.usal.bisite.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/es.usal.bisite.example-1/lib/arm, /data/app/es.usal.bisite.example-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]'
    r0 00000000  r1 00007dbc  r2 00000006  r3 b6f3bb7c
    r4 b6f3bb84  r5 b6f3bb34  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
    r8 b4abf378  r9 b4c6a800  sl 00000001  fp 00000001
    ip 00000006  sp be84fe68  lr b6ca0c51  pc b6ca3040  cpsr 40070010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00042040  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 0003fc4d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
    #02 pc 0001c3fb  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 000195ad  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
    #04 pc 00017500  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 003339f9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+228)
    #06 pc 000f460b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2226)
    #07 pc 0025aa5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1550)
    #08 pc 0025ae0d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, std::__va_list)+64)
    #09 pc 000fd1e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+32)
    #10 pc 001022f5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::JniValueType*) (.constprop.95)+5072)
    #11 pc 001146e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+392)
    #12 pc 000fb13b  /data/app/es.usal.bisite.example-1/lib/arm/libngnative.so (JniNG::JniNG(_JavaVM*, _JNIEnv*&)+554)
    #13 pc 000e1d6f  /data/app/es.usal.bisite.example-1/lib/arm/libngnative.so (JNI_OnLoad+58)
    #14 pc 0025b397  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::LoadNativeLibrary(_JNIEnv*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, _jobject*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+1238)
    #15 pc 002d145f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime_nativeLoad(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+194)
    #16 pc 739f427d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x235e000)
```

**(UPDATE2)**
I solve this adding this proguard rule:

```
#SKOBBLER
-keep class com.skobbler.** { *; }
```

Could you tell me some specific rules?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a  hot fix for 2.5.1 SDK for compiling for API level 23: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gcf3gmex3oz8l9/API_Level%2023_Fix.zip?dl=0

Please test it out and let us know if everything it’s ok.

Comment: es, now it works and the warning has disappeared. But now on runtime i have the following issue: **(UPDATE 1)**

Comment: Is the issue still present?

Comment: update 2 is not a solution... if you want to proguard part of skobbler then this does not help you